# picasso does not display photos from the gallery

Tags: java, android

I want to add a photo from the gallery using picasso to imageView, but it is not displayed, photos from the Internet are displayed and those that were photographed from the camera are not

```
enter code here


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {


        image_uri = data.getData();


        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(image_uri)
                .error(R.drawable.defaultimage)
                .into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        image.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                });

    } else {
        //startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MyActivity.class));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In High API level devices. you need to add this line in Manifest Application tag

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: I added as you said, but when I test applications in the console, it gives this     C:\Users\USER\Desktop\myProject\myTestApp\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml:23: error: attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found.
  error: failed processing manifest.

Comment: Let try after change 
   compileSdkVersion = 29
    minSdkVersion = 21

Comment: changed but not displayed again, but when I use Picasso.get (). load (). into (image);, everything works out well only some photos are rotated 90 degrees if you can help solve this problem I will be very grateful